# Подключение к потоку при не нажатой кнопке "Плей"

Tags: php, html5, javascript

Суть проблемы в следующем, есть плеер каталога радиостанций http://radiomaniya.ru/player.php?id=optimistfm который сделан на HTML 5, когда его ставят на сайте то он сразу подключает пользователя к потоку, хотя пользователь, посетивший сайт, не включил его даже получается накрутка слушателей...

Помогите решить проблему...

Comment: radiomania.ru это ваш сайт ?

Comment: @eicto, логично, что нет.

Comment: ну естественно мой, по вашему бы я задавал подобный вопрос здесь =)

Comment: @Zhukov Roman видите, иногда логика не работает, удалите ответ плз, чтобы не вводит в заблуждение нагугливших

Comment: @eicto, спасибо. Странно, сайт его, а разобраться не может.

Comment: ты совсем? просто именно это я не знаю... самый умный тоже мне нашелся...

Comment: @Zhukov Roman плагин то не его, и там действительно я не нашел кошерного способа притормозить загрузку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

src сразу не выставляйте:

HTML:

```
<audio id="audio-player" src="#" data-src="http://radio.trance-life.ru:8000/ambient192mp3"
type="audio/mp3" controls="controls" preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>
```

скрипт измените вот так:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var real_src=$('#audio-player').data('src'); //запоминаем data-src
                                                 //в real_src
    player = new MediaElementPlayer('#audio-player', {
        alwaysShowControls: true,
        features: ['playpause', 'volume'],
        audioVolume: 'horizontal',
        audioWidth: 200,
        audioHeight: 50,
        startVolume: 0.5
    });
    $('.audio-player .mejs-play').one('click', function () { //первый раз
        console.log(real_src);                               //по кнопке play
        player.setSrc(real_src);                            //выставляем src
        player.play();
        return false;
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/odivuk/1/edit)

Comment: простите за немного лупый вопрос: в смысле, что значит - src сразу не выставляйте?

Comment: в элементе audio, я заапдейтил ответ, вроде работает, может  посмотреть в консоли сети браузера.

Comment: btw,у вас там громкость по умолчанию на половину, могут быть немалые искажения от софтового микшера (я колонки тестировал недавно, и изменение громкости в веб плеерах смазывает звук немного)

Comment: чтобы еще уменьшить нагрузку на сервер, положите скрипт в файл а jquery и mediaelement возьмете с сdn http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!mediaelement http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!jquery